# Can I copy a MySQL database by copying the files? What do the files contain exactly?

Tags: mysql, database

I am using MySQL database and using an Ubuntu Linux machine.

My database named `db_test` , I notice that under path `/var/lib/mysql/db_test` ,there are files suffix with `.frm`, `.MYD`, `.MYI` like following:

```
/var/lib/mysql/db_test# ls

cars.frm 
cars.MYD 
cars.MYI

customers.frm
customers.MYD
customers.MYI

departments.frm
departments.MYD
departments.MYI

...
```

Seems each `.frm`, `.MYD`, `.MYI` files group mapped with one table in the database.

I have following two questions to ask:

1. What are the three files doing exactly?
2. If I create a new directory under path `/var/lib/mysql/` say `db_test_2` , and copy every file from `db_test_1` directory to `db_test_2` , will it also create a new database `db_test_2` which has exactly the same contents(tables) as `db_test_1`'s ?

Does this physically database files moving action create the same result as following command-line actions:

1. dump the database `db_test_1` out
2. create a new database `db_test_2`
3. then dump the `db_test_1` database back into the new database `db_test_2`?

If so, it seems moving files are much faster then using `mysqldump` to copy databases(or to importing data from one DB to another DB in MySQL). Any opinions on this?

Answer (score 9):

1. AFAIR, .frm is description-file (where database table stucture described), .MYD is file with data, .MYI is file with indexes.
2. Yes, copying will be much faster. But there's one problem: it's not atomic. Under high load copied files will be inconsistent and maybe even corrupted at all. Especially if you are using some more 'smart' engine like InnoDB.

**Edit:** p.s. You can safely copy these files, but before you should stop mysql server.

Answer (score 4):

You have a cmd-line tool which does exactly this: `mysqlhotcopy`

It works fine wy myisam tables, but not with InnoDb tables.

If you have configured your server with lvm, and put your /var/lib/mysql on a dedicated volume here is the way I recommend to backup very fast and in a non-blocking way all your databases:

```
mysql -U root -p
  > flush tables with read lock;
```

This flushes all your tables to disk and blocks any r/w operation

```
  > system "lvcreate -s -L 1G -n lvMysql_snap /dev/vg_myserver/lv_mysql" ;
```

Needs to be adapted to your configuration, this creates a snapshot of the filesystem of your database. It takes no time

```
  > unlock tables;
```

This is done, R/W operation are resumed.

Now you can mount /dev/vg_myserver/lvMysql_snap and make a tar archive of your database!

Comment: This seems like a fast way to backup the db. But what about switching that snapshot back so it becomes my live database again? That's the part I'm really concerned about. I can `mysqldump` my db in under 2 seconds. Restoring it is the slow part, taking 5-10 minutes.

Comment: on recent distros lvm snapshots can be reverted to the origin, but it is probably  not what you want for for managing database backups.

Comment: Regarding mysqlhotcopy:"This utility is deprecated in MySQL 5.6.20 and removed in MySQL 5.7"
From: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlhotcopy.html]

Answer (score 2):

This'll work for MyISAM, but not for InnoDB.
See https://serverfault.com/a/367321/57569

From that answer, about InnoDB:

> If you are thinking of just copying the .frm and .ibd file, you are in line for world of hurting. Copying the .frm and .ibd file of an InnoDB table is only good if you can guarantee that the tablespace id of the .ibd file matches exactly with the tablespace id entry in the metdata of the ibdata1 file.

Answer (score 0):

I find `mysqldump | mysql` method too slow for cloning 6GB database even on the same machine/mysql-server, so I tried copying entire datadir folder of the db and attempted to paste it on a different folder (same instance) for other db where I can mess with it. turns out, it appears to be corrupted when starting the mysql.. tried to set auto_recover table, but no luck.

I guess it would only work on the same database name. what I did is to create 2 docker container running mysql, 1 as slave of my production's slave, and one for direct replicating via docker mapping files. see my structure below.

```
          +-----------+
          | Master DB |
          +-----------+
                |
 (Replication)  |
        +-----------------+
        | Slave/Master DB |
        +-----------------+
                |
                |         Cloud / Production Server
                V
======================================================================
                |
                |         My Local Computer
 (Replication)  |
          +-----------+    - Docker Container: AppDBLive.readonly
          | Slave  DB |    - DB Name: MyAppDB
          +-----------+    - READ Only (If I want to test live data)
                |          - Consistently cloning from prod slave/master
                |
  (Rsync/Copy datadir of MyAppDB)
                |
                V
        +----------------+  - Docker Container: AppDBLive.readwrite
        | No Replication |  - DB Name: MyAppDB
        +----------------+  - Can Write and mess with all the data for testing/dev
                            - clone via sh script to trigger rsync from AppDBLive.read
```

Here's my script for building my docker containers:

/local/path/to/AppDBLive.readonly/run.sh:

```
_PWD=`pwd`
docker run --name=MyAppDB \
--mount type=bind,src=$_PWD/my.cnf,dst=/etc/my.cnf \
--mount type=bind,src=$_PWD/datadir,dst=/var/lib/mysql \
--mount type=bind,src=$_PWD/logs,dst=/var/log/mysql \
-p 3336:3306 \
-d mysql/mysql-server:5.7
```

/local/path/to/AppDBLive.readwrite/run.sh:

```
_PWD=`pwd`
docker run --name=MyAppDB.dev \
--mount type=bind,src=$_PWD/my.cnf,dst=/etc/my.cnf \
--mount type=bind,src=$_PWD/datadir,dst=/var/lib/mysql \
--mount type=bind,src=$_PWD/logs,dst=/var/log/mysql \
-p 3337:3306 \
-d mysql/mysql-server:5.7
```

Note the difference on port numbers of both containers. make sure your app is connecting to the right ports.

Also make sure when you run clone script, both containers are off.